# Is it possible to programmatically change a user's screen saver and/or desktop background?

Tags: windows, wallpaper

I have been asked to standardize the screen saver and desktop background used by everyone in my company and, aside from going around to each PC individually, I'm looking for a programmatic way to accomplish this.  I am not a systems admin, so have never crossed this bridge before.  It is also worth noting that most PCs are running Windows XP, however some are Windows Server 2003 and a few are Vista.

Comment: If PC's are member of domain then Rich B's suggestion is the way forward.

Comment: Why is this question voted down?

Comment: @Airsource: Who cares? If you don't agree, vote it up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just use [Group Policies](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/prork/prdb_cdk_ugxd.mspx?mfr=true)?

Answer (score 6):

[Changing screensaver in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ScreenSaverControl.aspx)

[Changing desktop in VB.net](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19517-change-wallpaper-using-vb-net.aspx)